# External access to Kafka using Strimzi

Tags: kubernetes, networking, apache-kafka, infrastructure, strimzi

I'm attempting to provide bi-direction external access to Kafka using Strimzi by following this guide: [Red Hat Developer - Kafka in Kubernetes](https://redhat-developer-demos.github.io/kafka-tutorial/kafka-tutorial/1.0.x/07-kubernetes.html)

My YAML taken from the [Strimizi examples on GitHub](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/blob/main/examples/kafka/kafka-ephemeral.yaml), is as follows:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.0.0
    replicas: 1 #3
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: loadbalancer
        tls: false
        configuration:
          #externalTrafficPolicy: Local
          #loadBalancerSourceRanges:
          #  - 10.0.0.200/32
          brokers:
          - broker: 0
            advertisedHost: 10.0.0.200
            advertisedPort: 30123
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1 #3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1 #3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1 #2
      log.message.format.version: "3.0"
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.0"
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1 #3
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

When running `kubectl get services` I'm presented with the following:

```
NAME                                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                               AGE
kubernetes                            ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                               48m
my-cluster-kafka-0                    LoadBalancer   10.107.190.96   <pending>     9094:31964/TCP                        29m
my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap            ClusterIP      10.99.34.246    <none>        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP            43m
my-cluster-kafka-brokers              ClusterIP      None            <none>        9090/TCP,9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   43m
my-cluster-kafka-external-bootstrap   LoadBalancer   10.99.91.68     <pending>     9094:31442/TCP                        29m
my-cluster-zookeeper-client           ClusterIP      10.101.216.35   <none>        2181/TCP                              45m
my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes            ClusterIP      None            <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP            45m
```

Note the `my-cluster-kafka-0` and `my-cluster-kafka-external-bootstrap` has a `<pending>` `EXTERNAL-IP`. What am I missing within my YAML file to provide bi-direction external access to `my-cluster-kafka-0`?

Comment: I've kept on digging through the Strimzi documentation and found [5.2. Setting up access for clients outside of Kubernetes](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/deploying.html#setup-external-clients-str) where the example specifies an `authorization` section. Would this still be required if I were to be testing with [kcat](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat)?

Comment: Above then conflicts with [3.2. Accessing Kafka using loadbalancers](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/using.html#proc-accessing-kafka-using-loadbalancers-str) but reveals that all I may be missing is a CA Certificate. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strimzi just created the Kubernetes Service of type `Loadbalancer`. It is up to your Kubernetes cluster to provision the load balancer and set its external address which Strimzi can use. When the external address is listed as `pending` it means the load balancer is not (yet) created. In some public clouds that can take few minutes, so it might be just about waiting for it. But keep in mind that the load balancers are not supported in all environments => and when they are not supported, you cannot really use them. So you really need to double check whether your environment supports them or not. Typically, different clouds would support load balancers while some local or bare-metal environments might not (but it really depends).

I'm also not really sure why did you configured the advertised host and port:

```yaml
            advertisedHost: 10.0.0.200
            advertisedPort: 30123
```

When using load balancers (assuming they would be supported in your environments), you would normally want to use the loadbalancer address which will be automatically set as the advertised host / port. Apart from that, your YAML looks good, but the loadbalancer support might be missing.

Comment: Thanks for your work on Strimzi Jakub! It's a real life saver for someone like me trying to just get things working without having to learn K8s :).

Understood, I'll need to check the MiniKube documentation then. Me adding the advertisedHost & advertisedPort is a last ditch attempt to get something working.

Comment: For anyone else in the same boat, it was user error. You need to run `minikube tunnel` for MiniKube to generate generate the IP. See [How to access applications running within minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) for more information.